# Different texture in Cylinder in X3D

Tags: xml, textures, x3d

Does anybody know if it is possible to have different textures for the top, bottom and side in a cylinder in X3D?

For example if I want to design a weel, I create a cylinder and apply the rim texture. From the top und bottom it looks good but the texture is also applied to the side and this looks realy silly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the top and bottom caps pf the Cylinder by setting the to and bottom field to FALSE. Use instead two Disk2D nodes for the caps. On the Disk2D you can apply different textures.